# overlaying plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How to overlay one plot on top of the other in ggplot2 as explained in the following sentences? I want to draw the grey time series on top of the red one using ggplot2 in R (now the red one is above the grey one and I want my graph to be the other way around). Here is my code (I generate some data in order to show you my problem, the real dataset is much more complex):

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)

time <- rep(1:100,2)
timeseries <- c(rep(0.5,100),rep(c(0,1),50))
upper <- c(rep(0.7,100),rep(0,100))
lower <- c(rep(0.3,100),rep(0,100))
legend <- c(rep("red should be under",100),rep("grey should be above",100))

dataset <- data.frame(timeseries,upper,lower,time,legend)

ggplot(dataset, aes(x=time, y=timeseries)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=legend, size=legend)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=upper, ymin=lower, fill=legend), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_colour_manual(limits=c("grey should be above","red should be under"),values = c("grey50","red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(NA, "red")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(0.5, 1.5)) +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal",legend.title = element_blank())
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data for the data frame?

Comment: use `alpha` parameter in your geom line

Comment: I don't want to change the level of transparency of one time-series but I want one of them to be above the other. You can also now run the codenow, I have added some data in the original post.

Comment: just swap the order. put your `geom_line` statement at the end so that the gray line layer is the last drawn and hence right on top.

Comment: I already tried this and it doesn't work. Maybe because I also want to add a legend with the "aes(colour=legend, size=legend)" statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data you are grouping on into a factor and explicitly set the order of the levels. `ggplot` draws the layers according to this order. Also, it is a good idea to group the `scale_manual` codes to the `geom` it is being applied to for readability.

```
legend <- factor(legend, levels = c("red should be under","grey should be above"))

c <- data.frame(timeseries,upper,lower,time,legend)

ggplot(c, aes(x=time, y=timeseries)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=upper, ymin=lower, fill=legend), alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", NA)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=legend, size=legend)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","grey50")) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1.5,0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal",legend.title = element_blank())
```

Note that the ordering of the values in the scale_manual now maps to "grey" and "red"

[image]